# xpages : Filtering a View Data Source using the keys parameter(filter by category name)

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I have an XPage linked to one of our databases which displays an history view of documents in this database.
This view is categorized in the Notes client.
I need to filter this data view by a value selected from a ComboBox, so I have limited the data to a single category by adding a parameter categoryFilter :" filter by category name".

The problem is that the display of the filtered view takes a lot of times then it appears to me a time error message.

N.B: The history view is very voluminous.

Can any one help me please to fix this problem.
thank you.

@modified : 29/07/2016

when i use Filter by column value : i have just the first document
[Filter by column value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t77s3.png)

But when i use Filter by category name : i have a complete result
[Filter by category name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxZrt.png)

Comment: Does it work if you delete the "Search in view results" code? It does a full text search and might take some time if database is not full text indexed.

Comment: but the problem occur even when i don't use "Search in view results" !

Answer (score 0):

Use "**Filter by column value**" instead of "Filter by category name".

Your source code should look like this then:

```
<xp:viewPanel
    ...
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView
            var="view1"
            viewName=...
            keys="#{javascript:sessionScope.categoryKey}">
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>
```

Comment: This resolves the problem of slow-down but does not make all documents requested.
It makes me only a part: for each value of selected IP it was a document display categorize by date

Comment: It should show you all documents for a given category in view. Make sure all documents you want to get are within this category in view.

Comment: i can't understand the difference between "Filter by column value" and  "Filter by category name" : both of them set the keys property of the data source.

Comment: No, "Filter by category name" sets property "categoryFilter". Only "Filter by column value" sets property "keys".

Comment: please show the post modification to understand me.

Comment: What do you mean by "post modification"?

Comment: @modified : 29/07/2016

when i use Filter by column value : i have just the first document Filter by column value

But when i use Filter by category name : i have a complete result Filter by category name

Comment: I guess you search for IP. If so, your view has to be categorized by IP as first sorted column. Is this the case?

Comment: yes it is. But also they are 3 other category : year, month, day after the IP category

Comment: This shouldn't matter. Could you show how does this view and your current XPages code look like, please.